# Open activity whith specific fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a wizard and i use fragments for every screen, on the last activity i have a button to send the user to accessibility on settings and when the user come back to my app that button have to change to something else, the problem is when the user get back to my app the button doesn't change so i want to close the activity and reopen it on the last fragment, in that way the button make the change correctly

How can i open the activity on the `SecurityWizardFiveFragment();`?

I use an adapter to set the order of the fragments:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position)
    {
    case 0:
        return new SecurityWizardOneFragment();
    case 1:
         return new SecurityWizardTwoFragment();            
    case 2:
        return new SecurityWizardThreeFragment();
    case 3:
        return new SecurityWizardFourFragment();
    case 4:
        return new SecurityWizardFiveFragment();

    }
    return null;

}
```

My SecurityWizardActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.security_wizard_info_tab);
    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new SecurityWizardViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs,this);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);       

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);      

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                @Override
                public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                    return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
                }
            });

    //Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);



}

private void installShortcut() {
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecurityWizardActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_lycos));
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

SecurityWizardFiveFragment, here i send the user to accessibility:

```
                if(accesabilityIsActive){
                ImageView accessibilitya = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.accessibility);
                accessibilitya.setImageResource(R.drawable.acces2);
                accessibilitya.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
                          startActivity(intent);
                      }
                    });
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem? you didn't any questions

Comment: Post also the code of your activity

Comment: sorry, its there now

Answer (score -1):

make a global variable `securityWizardPage`

on my SecurityWizardActivity

```
pager.setCurrentItem(Globals.securityWizardPage);
```

then when i want to open on a specific fragment:

```
Globals.securityWizardPage = 4;
```